# Laravel Datatables submit form via ajax source

Tags: laravel-4, datatables

I want to submit a form fields via Datatables ajax source and i did it like follow:

Form

```
<form id="search_fields">
    <input type="text" name="condition" value='1'>
</form>
```

Table

```
<table class="table" id="list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>بارکد</th>
                    <th>نمبر صادره مرجع</th>
                    <th>نمبر وارده#</th>
                    <th>مرجع ارسال کننده</th>
                    <th>وضعیت سند</th>
                    <th>عملیه</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Datatable configuration js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#list').dataTable( 
{
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{URL::to('/docscom/getSearchResultData')}}",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": $('#search_fields').serialize(),
            "success": function(response)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        }, 

        'sDom': 'lf<"clearfix">tip',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 1,
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        //"sAjaxSource": "{{URL::to('/docscom/getSearchResultData')}}",
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
        { 'sWidth': '30px' },
        { 'sWidth': '100px' },
        { 'sWidth': '130px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '250px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '130px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '100px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '100px', 'sClass': 'center' }
        ],
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "نمایش _MENU_ ریکارد در هر صفحه",
            "zeroRecords": "ریکارد موجود نیست",
            "info": "نمایش صفحه _PAGE_ از _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "ریکارد موجود نیست",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered از _MAX_ مجموع ریکارد)"
        }
    }
); 

});
</script>
```

Controller function

```
//get search result
    public function getSearchResultDataTable()
    {
        print_r($_POST);exit;
        //get result from database
        $result = Docscom::getSearchResult();

        return Datatables::of($result)
                            ->add_column('operations', '<a href="{{URL::route(\'getDocDetails\',$id)}}" class="table-link">
                                                                    <span class="fa-stack">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </a>')
                            //->set_row_class('@if($status==0) danger @elseif($status == 1) success @endif')
                            //->set_row_data('Test','{{$status}}')
                            ->make();
    }
```

Ajax Print_r Post Response

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => o
    [2] => n
    [3] => d
    [4] => i
    [5] => t
    [6] => i
    [7] => o
    [8] => n
    [9] => =
    [10] => 1
    [draw] => 1
    [columns] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 0
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 1
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 3
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 4
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 5
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 6
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

        )

    [order] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column] => 1
                    [dir] => desc
                )

        )

    [start] => 0
    [length] => 1
    [search] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
            [regex] => false
        )

)
```

Any one can tell me what is wrong my code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is it "*wrong*"? Does it so anything? Does it throw an exception? Does it make your computer hang? Does it give you the wrong result? etc. Please be specific in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using [ajax.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) correctly, only object or function is accepted.

Your ajax.data property should be changed to:

```
"data": function(d){
   $.each($('#search_fields').serializeArray(), function(i, obj){
      d['form_' + obj['name']] = obj['value'];
   });
}
```

This will add `form_` parameters with element names appended to server-side request. I'm using `form_` prefix to avoid name collision with other DataTables parameters (such as `start`, `length`, `search`, etc.) please modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use this for **dynamic input attributes**

```
         ajax: {
                url:"your_url",
                type:"post",
                data: function(d){
                    $.each($('#filterform').serializeArray(), function(i, obj){                        
                        if(!d[obj['name']]) d[obj['name']] = [];
                        d[obj['name']].push(obj['value']);
                    });
                }                    
            },
```